# Trying to get property 'access_token' of non-object laravel-google-sheets

Tags: laravel, request, google-sheets-api

Good Night,I'm using google api sheets with laravel following this tutorial

https://github.com/kawax/laravel-google-sheets

when I try to do the first example

```
use Sheets;
$user = $request->user();
$token = [
  'access_token'  => $user->access_token,
  'refresh_token' => $user->refresh_token,
  'expires_in'    => $user->expires_in,
  'created'       => $user->updated_at->getTimestamp(),
];

// all() returns array
$values = Sheets::setAccessToken($token)->spreadsheet('spreadsheetId')->sheet('Sheet 1')->all();
```

my code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Sheets;
use Google;
class PlanilhaController extends Controller
{
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user();
     $token = [
               'access_token'  => $user->access_token,
               'refresh_token'=> $user->refresh_token,
               'expires_in'=> $user->expires_in,
               'created' => $user->updated_at->getTimestamp(),
     ];
  $values = Sheets::setAccessToken($token) 
  >spreadsheet('spreadsheetId')->sheet('Sheet 1')->all();
   // all() returns array
    return view('planilha', compact('values'));
}
```

error: Trying to get property 'access_token' of non-object

which is not requested, but I do not know how to solve it

Comment: I did not read the tutorial, but apparently the request does not have user information, and the $user variable remains with null value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need that token, what you need is to set up your `.env` so it has following key

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_NAME=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=
GOOGLE_REDIRECT=

GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY=
GOOGLE_SERVICE_ENABLED=
GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION=

POST_SPREADSHEET_ID=
POST_SHEET_ID=
```

then in your controller

```
$sheets = Sheets::spreadsheet(config('sheets.post_spreadsheet_id'))
                        ->sheet(config('sheets.post_sheet_id'))
                        ->get();
        $header = $sheets->pull(0);
        $posts = Sheets::collection($header, $sheets);
        $posts = $posts->reverse()->take(10);
```

then in your config file write this

```
'post_spreadsheet_id' => env('POST_SPREADSHEET_ID'),
'post_sheet_id'       => env('POST_SHEET_ID'),
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response.  What information is in the fields and where do I find them?  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_NAME=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=
GOOGLE_REDIRECT=

GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY=
GOOGLE_SERVICE_ENABLED=
GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_LOCATION=                                                   would be referring to google sheet api or my google cloud profile?